# Dynamic aggregation in SQL (Hive)

Tags: hadoop, hive, aggregation

I have two tables. Table A with 3 columns: userid, a start date, and end date. Table B with events and datetimestamps. I would like to aggregate Table B up to the datetimes between the start and end date based on Table A. So something like...

```
select a.userid, count(distinct b.eventid) as events
from table a
inner join table b
on a.userid=b.userid
and b.datetime between a.starttime and b.endtime
group by a.userid
```

But Hive doesn't like that... I'm using Hadoop HortonWorks. Would appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `between` condition to `where` as only equality conditions in `join`s are supported prior to version 2.2.0.

[From Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-JoinOptimization)

> Complex expressions in ON clause are supported, starting with Hive 2.2.0 (see HIVE-15211, HIVE-15251). Prior to that, Hive did not support join conditions that are not equality conditions.